# OpsHub Migration Tool Stuck at "Reading and Analysis"

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I started a migration source code from TFS (not work items) to Visual Studio Online and it has been running for more than 24 hours but the status still shows "Reading and Analysis". CPU usage for the application is showing 0.

Should I keep waiting or is there a way to find out if an exception is thrown? I am not too familiar with debugging procedure for Java applications.

Answer (score 0):

Which version you are using? 
There is performance issue with label which is fixed in version 1.0.1.005.
Can you try current version?

Comment: I am using OVSMU-V1.0.1.005. I am migrating only TFS source code. I stopped the migration process and re-run the process.I left it running over the weekend. It is still stuck at "Reading and Analysis".

Comment: Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location <c or d>:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com
Please include a reference to this request in your email
so we will provide proper resolution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Error : TF14045: The identity 19b7a3e0-b25b-4c48-90a8-813202d6d1b4 is not a recognized identity.

above error comes while connecting to tfs server that's why utility continuously displaying reading and analysis because everytime utility connects to source TFS for fetching total number of change sets and lables it encounters same error.

As per microsoft blogs, people are encountering this type of issue after upgradation/db restore for collection. After this process when user tries to connect tfs, it always throws the same error which you have encountered. Have you done any of the above process for the collection you are trying to migrate? You can refer following thread which contains resolution for same error.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b67ad1d6-d763-4602-bf14-489a3389a30d/getting-tf14045-the-identity-guid-is-not-a-recognized-identity-after-db-restored?forum=tfsadmin

Let us know in case you won't be able to resolve this with the above information and also in case you have not done any upgradation/db restore procedure. In that case we would like to know your source tfs version and older upgrade history of this instance (If any).